# YOLOv8 With Audio Feedback

Tags: python, object, text-to-speech, detection, yolov8

I'm trying to make an audio feedback system for the YOLOv8 model which is used for object detection. It takes live footage from my webcam & uses the stream to detect objects. However, I want to make an addition to it such that the detected objects are spoken using text-to-speech. I've been trying for over an week & upon failure after failure, I decided it's finally time to get some help. Here's the code I'm using for detecting objects through my webcam:

```
# Python

from ultralytics import YOLO
from PIL import Image
import cv2

model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
results = model.predict(source="0", show=True)
```

I tried to convert the printed results into speech, but no matter what I try, I'm never able to hear the printed results (yes I've checked my audio playback & everything, no hardware issue)

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import pyttsx3

# Initialize text-to-speech engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()

model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")

# Make predictions
results = model.predict(source="0", show=True)

# Convert results to a string
results_str = str(results)

# Print results
print(results_str)

# Speak the results
engine.say(results_str)
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.